# Neovim setup on MS Windows

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to switch from Gvim to Neovim. Most tutorials are about Linux and not how to setup Neovim on MS Windows?

Two problems:

1. vimrc

   From the [document](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim) it's `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`

   But I don't want to put the vimrc file on C:\, it would be formatted when reinstalling the system. The old Gvim 8.0 can use a `.vimrc` in the same directory. Does Neovim support this?
2. vimfiles

   my previous directory structure looks like:

   ```
    d:\vim\  
          |--- vim80\
               | --- gvim.exe
               | --- ...
          |--- vimfiles\    <--- where to put this folder now?
   ```

   Where do I have to put the `vimfiles` folder for Neovim? I can't find any tutorial about this. From the `:h nvim-from-vim`, there are some directories which I tried without any luck.

   1. ~/vimfiles
   2. ~/.vim/vimfiles
   3. ~/AppData/vimfiles
   4. ~/AppData/Local/vimfiles
   5. ~/AppData/Local/nvim/vimfiles
   6. ~/AppData/Local/nvim-data/vimfiles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user's runtime directory is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim`.  When `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` isn't set (which is the typical case), then the default directory is `~/AppData/Local` on Windows and `~/.config` elsewhere.

```
OS         | Vim        | nvim
-----------|------------|---------------------
Windows    | ~/vimfiles | ~/AppData/Local/nvim
*nix/macOS | ~/.vim     | ~/.config/nvim
```

See `:help vimrc`, `:help xdg`, and `:help 'runtimepath'` for more detailed information.

Since you want to change where nvim's config is stored, then you should set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` in your environment to where you want the `nvim` directory to live.  If you wanted your nvim config to be at `D:\foo\nvim`, you would set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to `D:\foo`.

Comment: I was expecting Neovim uses `vimfiles` as directory name, but actually it uses `nvim` now. I linked the old directory with `mklink /D d:\Neovim\nvim d:\vim\vimfiles`, and linked the old vimrc with `mklink d:\Neovim\nvim\init.vim d:\vim\.vimrc`, seems working now.

Comment: To show the exact config directory, we can also use `:echo stdpath('config')` inside Neovim. This is univerally true for all systems, so novice users are not confused any more.

Answer (score 6):

Following the instructions in:

```
:h nvim-from-vim
```

may give you some ideas. For example, it details the new $XDG_CONFIG_HOME system of config management.

It's worth considering putting your vim config files on github (other cloud services are available).  You'll never again worry about forgetting to update other vim installations with changes to your config.