# Where do I put my "vimrc" file for Neovim on Windows?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, microsoft-windows

`:help nvim-from-vim` says:

> create `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` with these contents:
>
> ```
> set runtimepath+=~/.vim,~/.vim/after
> set packpath+=~/.vim
> source ~/.vimrc
> ```

and:

> If your system sets `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, use that instead of `~/.config`

But those paths aren't correct for Windows.

Vim for Windows reads from `~/_vimrc` on startup. What's the corresponding file for Neovim?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Neovim looks for `~\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim` to run at startup.

If you want to create the suggested `init.vim` from `:help nvim-from-vim`, save the following instead:

```
set runtimepath+=~/vimfiles,~/vimfiles/after
set packpath+=~/vimfiles
source ~/_vimrc
```

Then you can save all your settings to `~\_vimrc` just like you did with Vim.

See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12596/13438) and `:help vimrc` for more info.